# Select SQL Server database size

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

how can i query my sql server to only get the size of database?

I used this :

```
use "MY_DB"
exec sp_spaceused
```

I got this :

```
database_name   database_size   unallocated space
My_DB           17899.13 MB 5309.39 MB
```

It returns me several column that i don't need, maybe there is a trick to select database_size column from this stored procedure ?

I also tried this code :

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
       Name AS Logical_Name,
       Physical_Name,
       (size * 8) / 1024 SizeMB
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = 'MY_DB'
```

It gives me this result:

```
DatabaseName    Logical_Name    Physical_Name                    SizeMB
MY_DB           MY_DB           D:\MSSQL\Data\MY_DB.mdf          10613
MY_DB           MY_DB_log       D:\MSSQL\Data\MY_DB.ldf          7286
```

So i wrote this:

```
SELECT SUM(SizeMB)
FROM (
    SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
           Name AS Logical_Name,
           Physical_Name,
           (size * 8) / 1024 SizeMB
    FROM sys.master_files
    WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = 'MY_DB'
) AS TEMP
```

I got: 1183

So it works but maybe there is a proper way to get this?

Comment: same result would be with this 'SELECT SUM((size*8)/1024) SizeMB
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = 'YOUR_DB''

Comment: @LittlBobbyTables How can i add MB in the column? I want "MB" after the value

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
      database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
    , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
    , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
WHERE database_id = DB_ID() -- for current db 
GROUP BY database_id
```

**Output:**

```
-- my query
name           log_size_mb  row_size_mb   total_size_mb
-------------- ------------ ------------- -------------
xxxxxxxxxxx    512.00       302.81        814.81

-- sp_spaceused
database_name    database_size      unallocated space
---------------- ------------------ ------------------
xxxxxxxxxxx      814.81 MB          13.04 MB
```

**Function:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDBSize] 
(
    @db_name NVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

  SELECT 
        database_name = DB_NAME(database_id)
      , log_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'LOG' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
      , row_size_mb = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc = 'ROWS' THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
      , total_size_mb = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
  FROM sys.master_files WITH(NOWAIT)
  WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@db_name)
      OR @db_name IS NULL
  GROUP BY database_id
```

**UPDATE 2016/01/22:**

Show information about size, free space, last database backups

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#space') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #space

CREATE TABLE #space (
      database_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    , data_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
    , log_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #space (database_id, data_used_size, log_used_size)
    SELECT
          DB_ID()
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN space_used END)
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN space_used END)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.[type], space_used = SUM(FILEPROPERTY(s.name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8. / 1024)
        FROM sys.database_files s
        GROUP BY s.[type]
    ) t;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT
      d.database_id
    , d.name
    , d.state_desc
    , d.recovery_model_desc
    , t.total_size
    , t.data_size
    , s.data_used_size
    , t.log_size
    , s.log_used_size
    , bu.full_last_date
    , bu.full_size
    , bu.log_last_date
    , bu.log_size
FROM (
    SELECT
          database_id
        , log_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , data_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , total_size = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    FROM sys.master_files
    GROUP BY database_id
) t
JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = t.database_id
LEFT JOIN #space s ON d.database_id = s.database_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
          database_name
        , full_last_date = MAX(CASE WHEN [type] = 'D' THEN backup_finish_date END)
        , full_size = MAX(CASE WHEN [type] = 'D' THEN backup_size END)
        , log_last_date = MAX(CASE WHEN [type] = 'L' THEN backup_finish_date END)
        , log_size = MAX(CASE WHEN [type] = 'L' THEN backup_size END)
    FROM (
        SELECT
              s.database_name
            , s.[type]
            , s.backup_finish_date
            , backup_size =
                        CAST(CASE WHEN s.backup_size = s.compressed_backup_size
                                    THEN s.backup_size
                                    ELSE s.compressed_backup_size
                        END / 1048576.0 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
            , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.database_name, s.[type] ORDER BY s.backup_finish_date DESC)
        FROM msdb.dbo.backupset s
        WHERE s.[type] IN ('D', 'L')
    ) f
    WHERE f.RowNum = 1
    GROUP BY f.database_name
) bu ON d.name = bu.database_name
ORDER BY t.total_size DESC
```

**Output:**

```
database_id name                             state_desc   recovery_model_desc total_size   data_size   data_used_size  log_size    log_used_size  full_last_date          full_size    log_last_date           log_size
----------- -------------------------------- ------------ ------------------- ------------ ----------- --------------- ----------- -------------- ----------------------- ------------ ----------------------- ---------
24          StackOverflow                    ONLINE       SIMPLE              66339.88     65840.00    65102.06        499.88      5.05           NULL                    NULL         NULL                    NULL
11          AdventureWorks2012               ONLINE       SIMPLE              16404.13     15213.00    192.69          1191.13     15.55          2015-11-10 10:51:02.000 44.59        NULL                    NULL
10          locateme                         ONLINE       SIMPLE              1050.13      591.00      2.94            459.13      6.91           2015-11-06 15:08:34.000 17.25        NULL                    NULL
8           CL_Documents                     ONLINE       FULL                793.13       334.00      333.69          459.13      12.95          2015-11-06 15:08:31.000 309.22       2015-11-06 13:15:39.000 0.01
1           master                           ONLINE       SIMPLE              554.00       492.06      4.31            61.94       5.20           2015-11-06 15:08:12.000 0.65         NULL                    NULL
9           Refactoring                      ONLINE       SIMPLE              494.32       366.44      308.88          127.88      34.96          2016-01-05 18:59:10.000 37.53        NULL                    NULL
3           model                            ONLINE       SIMPLE              349.06       4.06        2.56            345.00      0.97           2015-11-06 15:08:12.000 0.45         NULL                    NULL
13          sql-format.com                   ONLINE       SIMPLE              216.81       181.38      149.00          35.44       3.06           2015-11-06 15:08:39.000 23.64        NULL                    NULL
23          users                            ONLINE       FULL                173.25       73.25       3.25            100.00      5.66           2015-11-23 13:15:45.000 0.72         NULL                    NULL
4           msdb                             ONLINE       SIMPLE              46.44        20.25       19.31           26.19       4.09           2015-11-06 15:08:12.000 2.96         NULL                    NULL
21          SSISDB                           ONLINE       FULL                45.06        40.00       4.06            5.06        4.84           2014-05-14 18:27:11.000 3.08         NULL                    NULL
27          tSQLt                            ONLINE       SIMPLE              9.00         5.00        3.06            4.00        0.75           NULL                    NULL         NULL                    NULL
2           tempdb                           ONLINE       SIMPLE              8.50         8.00        4.50            0.50        1.78           NULL                    NULL         NULL                    NULL
```

Comment: The user that is executing the query must have at least the **sysadmin** SQL Server role, otherwise NULL is returned.

Comment: I have some VLDBs that cause DECIMAL(8,2) to yeild "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric." Changing DECIMAL(8,2) to DECIMAL(12,2) was the fix.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I had 100 000 rows that I dropped and then I checked the size given these exampels. Size is still about 14 GB.

Comment: @essej file size is not compacted automatically, rows are deleted by space is not recovered automatically. you need to dbcc shrkinkfile/shrinkdatabae for that.

Answer (score 102):

Log size for all databases can be found by `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)`  Reference [SQLPERF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-sqlperf-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Also compare the results with the following query's result

```
EXEC sp_helpdb @dbname= 'MSDB'
```

It produces result similar to the following

[image]

There is a good article - [Different ways to determine free space for SQL Server databases and database files](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1805/different-ways-to-determine-free-space-for-sql-server-databases-and-database-files/)

Answer (score 71):

Worked perfectly for me to calculate **SQL database size** in **SQL Server 2012**

```
exec sp_spaceused
```

[image]

Comment: This also works for Azure SQL V12 (maybe V10 works, but not tested). This should be the preferred method to use with a newer version of MS SQL Server. +1

Comment: OK! me also not tested on Azure Vx , hopefully it works on Azure.

Comment: While this does work, it only gives you the combined numbers of data and log.

Answer (score 8):

There are already a lot of great answers here but it's worth mentioning a simple and quick way to get the **SQL Server Database size with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)** using a standard report.

To run a report you need:

1. right-click on the database
2. go to Reports > Standard Reports > Disk Usage.

It prints a nice report:

[image]

Where the **Total space Reserved** is the total size of the database on the disk and it includes the size of all data files and the size of all transaction log files.

Under the hood, SSMS uses [dbo.sysfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysfiles-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view or [sys.database_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view (depending on the version of MSSQL)  and some kind of this query to get the Total space Reserved value:

```
SELECT sum((convert(dec (19, 2),  
convert(bigint,SIZE))) * 8192 / 1048576.0) db_size_mb
FROM dbo.sysfiles;
```

Answer (score 7):

***Check Database Size in SQL Server for both Azure and On-Premises-***

**Method 1 – Using ‘sys.database_files’ System View**

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME() AS [database_name],
    CONCAT(CAST(SUM(
        CAST( (size * 8.0/1024) AS DECIMAL(15,2) )
    ) AS VARCHAR(20)),' MB') AS [database_size]
FROM sys.database_files;
```

[image]

**Method 2 – Using ‘sp_spaceused’ System Stored Procedure**

```
EXEC sp_spaceused ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT      sys.databases.name AS [Database Name],  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(size)*8/1024)+' MB' AS [Size]  
     FROM        sys.databases   
     JOIN        sys.master_files  
     ON          sys.databases.database_id=sys.master_files.database_id  
     GROUP BY    sys.databases.name  
     ORDER BY    sys.databases.name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check how this query works following [this link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SIZE-OF-ALL-DATABASES-IN-0337f6d5/).

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#spacetable') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE tempdb..#spacetable 
create table #spacetable
(
database_name varchar(50) ,
total_size_data int,
space_util_data int,
space_data_left int,
percent_fill_data float,
total_size_data_log int,
space_util_log int,
space_log_left int,
percent_fill_log char(50),
[total db size] int,
[total size used] int,
[total size left] int
)
insert into  #spacetable
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?];
select x.[DATABASE NAME],x.[total size data],x.[space util],x.[total size data]-x.[space util] [space left data],
x.[percent fill],y.[total size log],y.[space util],
y.[total size log]-y.[space util] [space left log],y.[percent fill],
y.[total size log]+x.[total size data] ''total db size''
,x.[space util]+y.[space util] ''total size used'',
(y.[total size log]+x.[total size data])-(y.[space util]+x.[space util]) ''total size left''
 from (select DB_NAME() ''DATABASE NAME'',
sum(size*8/1024) ''total size data'',sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed'')*8/1024) ''space util''
,case when sum(size*8/1024)=0 then ''divide by zero'' else
substring(cast((sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed''))*1.0*100/sum(size)) as CHAR(50)),1,6) end ''percent fill''
from sys.master_files where database_id=DB_ID(DB_NAME())  and  type=0
group by type_desc  ) as x ,
(select 
sum(size*8/1024) ''total size log'',sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed'')*8/1024) ''space util''
,case when sum(size*8/1024)=0 then ''divide by zero'' else
substring(cast((sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed''))*1.0*100/sum(size)) as CHAR(50)),1,6) end ''percent fill''
from sys.master_files where database_id=DB_ID(DB_NAME())  and  type=1
group by type_desc  )y'
select * from #spacetable 
order by database_name
drop table #spacetable
```

Answer (score 3):

`EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1` 
show in 1 row all of the result

if you execute just 'EXEC sp_spaceused' you will see two rows
Work in SQL Server Management Studio v17.9

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME (database_id) as [Database Name],
    name as [Database File Name],
    [Type] = CASE WHEN Type_Desc = 'ROWS' THEN 'Data File(s)'
            WHEN Type_Desc = 'LOG'  THEN 'Log File(s)'
            ELSE Type_Desc END,
    size*8/1024 as 'Size (MB)',
    physical_name as [Database_File_Location]
FROM sys.master_files
ORDER BY 1,3
```

**Output**

```
Database Name               Database File Name              Type                Size (MB)   Database_File_Location
--------------------------- ------------------------------- ------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
AdventureWorksDW2017        AdventureWorksDW2017            Data File(s)        136         E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW2017.mdf
AdventureWorksDW2017        AdventureWorksDW2017_log        Log File(s)         72          E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksDW2017_log.ldf
DBA_Admin                   DBA_Admin                       Data File(s)        8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBA_Admin.mdf
DBA_Admin                   DBA_Admin_log                   Log File(s)         8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBA_Admin_log.ldf
EventNotifications          EventNotifications              Data File(s)        8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\EventNotifications.mdf
EventNotifications          EventNotifications_log          Log File(s)         8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\EventNotifications_log.ldf
master                      master                          Data File(s)        4           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
master                      mastlog                         Log File(s)         2           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
model                       modeldev                        Data File(s)        8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf
model                       modellog                        Log File(s)         8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf
msdb                        MSDBData                        Data File(s)        19          E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf
msdb                        MSDBLog                         Log File(s)         13          E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBLog.ldf
tempdb                      temp2                           Data File(s)        8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_2.ndf
tempdb                      temp3                           Data File(s)        8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_3.ndf
tempdb                      temp4                           Data File(s)        8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_4.ndf
tempdb                      tempdev                         Data File(s)        8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf
tempdb                      templog                         Log File(s)         8           E:\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\templog.ldf
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply check single database size, you can do it using SSMS Gui

Go to **Server Explorer -> Expand it -> Right click on Database -> Choose Properties -> In popup window choose General tab ->See Size**

Source: [Check database size in Sql server ( Various Ways explained)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/sql/check-database-size-in-sql-server-various-ways-explained/234)

Answer (score 0):

try below code. its very good code:

```
with CteDbSizes
as
(
    select database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 size
    from sys.master_files
)
select 
    dbFileSizes.[name] AS DatabaseName,
    (select sum(size) from CteDbSizes where type = 1 and CteDbSizes.database_id = dbFileSizes.database_id) LogFileSizeMB,
    (select sum(size) from CteDbSizes where type = 0 and CteDbSizes.database_id = dbFileSizes.database_id) DataFileSizeMB
from sys.databases dbFileSizes ORDER BY DataFileSizeMB desc
```

[image: Result of the above query]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get size of real data, you'll need to filter 'ONLINE' data files only. Otherwise you can get a size that significately different from the size you see in GUI. Some ghost | old garbage records can be in the sys.master_files, for example 'DEFUNCT' data files.

```
    with fs
    as
    (
        select database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 size, physical_name
        from sys.master_files
        where state_desc = 'ONLINE' -- ONLINE,RESTORING,RECOVERING,RECOVERY_PENDING,SUSPECT,,OFFLINE, DEFUNCT
    )
    select 
        name,
        (select sum(size) from fs where type = 0 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) DataFileSizeMB,
        (select sum(size) from fs where type = 1 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) LogFileSizeMB,
        (select sum(size) from fs where fs.database_id = db.database_id) TotalFileSizeMB
    from sys.databases db
    --order by database_id
    order by TotalFileSizeMB desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE procedure SP_DBSIZE
AS
IF (OBJECT_ID('db_size','U')) IS NOT NULL
    drop table DB_size
create table db_size(name nvarchar(100), db_size nvarchar(100), owner nvarchar(100), dbid int, created nvarchar(30), status nvarchar(255), compatibility_level nvarchar(10))
    insert into db_size
        exec sp_helpdb
        update db_size  set status = left(status,50)
        alter table db_size alter column status nvarchar(50)
select * from db_size
```