# Why Does SQL Server Log File Size Decrease

Tags: sql-server

I am using the SQL script on [Select SQL Server database size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014392/select-sql-server-database-size) in order to monitor how much my database file usage increased. I am particularly inspecting the "data_used_size" and "log_used_size" fields. But I notice that while the data file usage consistently increases after a set of activities, log file usage sometimes increases and sometimes decreases, thus always staying at a certain level. Why is this?

Comment: In short: stuff get written and stuff gets cleaned up. There are many guides to this. For starters what is the recovery model?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Full recovery.

Comment: I suggest you read the article posted in the answers below and ask a specific question if you have one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in [MSDN article about Transaction Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server#Truncation)

1. If the DB is using simple recovery model, after a checkpoint
2. If full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model is used, then after a log backup.

Comment: But I am using the full recovery model and not doing any backups in the meanwhile.

Comment: Is there a size restriction set in DB properties? Maybe there's a scheduled job to auto backup/

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken when I said it is in full recovery mode. I checked it again and it is in simple recovery mode. I will accept your answer.